# Panda data-frame column without labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following data set in panda dataframe

```
print  data
```

Result:

```
            Open   High    Low  Close  Adj Close   Volume
Date                                                      
2018-05-25  12.70  12.73  12.48  12.61  12.610000  1469800
2018-05-24  12.99  13.08  12.93  12.98  12.980000   814800
2018-05-23  13.19  13.30  13.06  13.12  13.120000  1417500
2018-05-22  13.46  13.57  13.25  13.27  13.270000  1189000
2018-05-18  13.41  13.44  13.36  13.38  13.380000   986300
2018-05-17  13.19  13.42  13.19  13.40  13.400000  1056200
2018-05-16  13.01  13.14  13.01  13.12  13.120000   481300
```

If I just want to print single column just close  it shows with the date index

```
print data.Low
```

Result:

```
Date
2018-05-25    12.48
2018-05-24    12.93
2018-05-23    13.06
2018-05-22    13.25
2018-05-18    13.36
2018-05-17    13.19
2018-05-16    13.01
```

Is there way to slice/print just the closing price. So the output will be like:

```
12.48
12.93
13.06
13.25
13.36
13.19
13.01
```

Comment: What is reason for it? Write to file? then use `df.Low.to_csv(file, index=False)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pandas `Series` and `DataFrame` always need some index values.

Default `RangeIndex` is possible create by:

```
print data.reset_index(drop=True).Low
```

But if need write only values to file as column without index and with no header:

```
data.Low.to_csv(file, index=False, header=None)
```

If need convert column to `list`:

```
print data.Low.tolist()
[12.48, 12.93, 13.06, 13.25, 13.36, 13.19, 13.01]
```

And for 1d numpy array:

```
print data.Low.values
[12.48 12.93 13.06 13.25 13.36 13.19 13.01]
```

If want 1xM array:

```
print (data[['Low']].values)
[[12.48]
 [12.93]
 [13.06]
 [13.25]
 [13.36]
 [13.19]
 [13.01]]
```

Comment: I need to extract just the closing price to another array. file wont work.

Comment: Then use `data.Low.values`

Comment: data.Low.tolist() does not work.  data.Low.values shows the "Date" at the top of column


Date
12.73
13.08
13.30
13.57
13.44

Comment: What is your code? `print (data.Low.values)` return 1d array, there is no header.

Comment: @user1795110 - Added outputs to answer

Comment: Thanks,   following line worked 
print data.Low.values